# Vehicles and Trucks

Tags: word-usage

At the entrance to the most prestigious university in Ghana, is the notice:

> NO ENTRY FOR COMMERCIAL VEHICLES AND TRUCKS

The same notice can be found at access roads to  and within the number 1 university of Ghana.

This part of the notice I have quoted IS COMPLETE!  I called the office of the vice-chancellor and sent an email to the same office (26 May 2016) asking that they look again at the use of both Vehicles and Trucks in the context. No reply has been received.  No action has been taken (18 July 2016).

Please help.  I have my doubts about trucks being different from vehicles. Could it be an "acceptable pleonasm"?

Ghana uses British English.
Thank you.

Comment: According to the *commercial vehicle* definition, trucks are commercial vehicle. I guess they added *trucks* for emphsis.

Comment: RE:  _I have my doubts about trucks being different from vehicles._ If you remove the word COMMERCIAL from the sign, you might have a valid point. As it is, the sign is trying to prevent entry for certain kinds of vehicles: commercial vehicles, and trucks. [This link](http://rwoinsurance.com/compliance-commercial-vehicle-regulations/) might help.

Answer (score 5):

Not all commercial vehicles are trucks and not all trucks are commercial vehicles.

Any vehicle used for commercial purposes could be described as a commercial vehicle.  This could include light vans or buses.
Any individual can own a truck for personal use.  It is not uncommon for individuals to own small trucks or pick-ups.

While it is true that the sign looks like tautology, perhaps they are just being emphatic and covering all options.  Perhaps it would be clearer if they simply quoted a weight limit.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I wonder if a light pickup truck would qualify as a "truck" in this context.

Comment: @J.R. You could still have a non-commercial truck. It's rare I suppose but I don't think there is anything really preventing me from buying an 18 wheeler and using it to commute to work other than parking issues and some city ordinances where I live.